# How to use Observable.FromEvent with SignalR Close event

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive, signalr-hub

SignalR Close event has the following definition:

```
public event Func<Exception, Task> Closed;
```

How can I use this with the Rx method Observable.FromEvent?

Observable.FromEvent definition looks to return an Action instead of a Func for all overloads

Comment: That duplicate should be bang on what you need.